# Select a single element by class name between multiple element with the same class name?

Tags: html, jquery

I have multiple elements with the same class name. I want to store `hexpaletteval` of the column (and `rgbpaletteval`, but I was thinking about converting it directly) at click of the corresponding `favcolor`, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Using my code (below) it obviously changes the background color to yellow to ALL `hexpalettecolor`, not only one. I change the color to have a visual to what I'm doing.

I want to be able to chose only the value of `hexpalettecolor` in the same column, so if `favcolor` 1 I want to select `hexpalettecolor` 1

[image]

```js
$(".favcolor").click(function() {
  $(".hexpaletteval").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/favorite",
    data: {
      colorhex: $(".hexpaletteval").val(),
      colorrgb: hextorgb(colorhex),
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="space">
  <div class="colorcoloumn">
    <div class="colorcoloumntext">
      <div class="hexpaletteval">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rgbpaletteval">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="favcolor">1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="colorcoloumn">
    <div class="colorcoloumntext">
      <div class="hexpaletteval">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rgbpaletteval">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="favcolor">2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="colorcoloumn">
    <div class="colorcoloumntext">
      <div class="hexpaletteval">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rgbpaletteval">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="favcolor">3</button>

  </div>
  <div class="colorcoloumn">
    <div class="colorcoloumntext">
      <div class="hexpaletteval">
        <p>4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rgbpaletteval">
        <p>4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="favcolor">4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="colorcoloumn" id="5">
    <div class="colorcoloumntext">
      <div class="hexpaletteval">
        <p>5</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rgbpaletteval">
        <p>5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="favcolor">5</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the content related to the button which raised the event you can use the `this` keyword in the event handler along with `closest()` and `find()` to traverse the DOM.

Also, `.hexpaletteval` is a `div` element and so has no `val()` to read. I presume that you're intending to read the text inside the element, so this should be `text()` instead.

Finally, note that I changed the use of `css()` in your JS code to `addClass()` instead. This is better practice as it removed the styling data from your JS code.

```js
$(".favcolor").click(function() {
  let $column = $(this).closest('.colorcoloumn');
  let $hexpaletteval = $column.find(".hexpaletteval").addClass('selected');
  
  let value = $hexpaletteval.text().trim();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```css
.selected { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="space">
  <div class="colorcoloumn">
    <div class="colorcoloumntext">
      <div class="hexpaletteval">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rgbpaletteval">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="favcolor">1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="colorcoloumn">
    <div class="colorcoloumntext">
      <div class="hexpaletteval">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rgbpaletteval">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="favcolor">2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="colorcoloumn">
    <div class="colorcoloumntext">
      <div class="hexpaletteval">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rgbpaletteval">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="favcolor">3</button>

  </div>
  <div class="colorcoloumn">
    <div class="colorcoloumntext">
      <div class="hexpaletteval">
        <p>4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rgbpaletteval">
        <p>4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="favcolor">4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="colorcoloumn" id="5">
    <div class="colorcoloumntext">
      <div class="hexpaletteval">
        <p>5</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rgbpaletteval">
        <p>5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="favcolor">5</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, thank you.
I have a question: why you use `let $column` and `let $hexpaletteval` instead of `let coloumn` and `let hexpaletteval`?

Comment: Glad to help. The `$` prefix is used to denote that the variable contains a jQuery object, more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14362939/519413